# Servicestack unauthorized exception after credential authentication is performed

Tags: servicestack-bsd

I'm trying to get Servicestack Credentials authentication to work but when I attempt to consume a protected service decorated with `[Authenticate]` I get an unauthorized exception even after the authentication has been successful. What is being missed here?

AppHost looks like this:

```
    AuthFeature authFeature = new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[]{                    
                new BpeCredentialsAuthProvider(), //HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials                                        
            }) { HtmlRedirect = null };
        authFeature.ServiceRoutes[typeof(AuthService)] = new[] { "/auth" };  
        authFeature.IncludeAssignRoleServices = false;
        Plugins.Add(authFeature);
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
```

I think I'm overriding `TryAuthenticate` correctly and from Swagger everything works properly. The problem resides in the client call -after the authentication against myurl/auth/ succeeds- the next call to a different service fails with unauthorized exception. Any idea please?

After more research: it looks like ss-id/ss-pid cookies need to be passed to the restricted resource to authenticate. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When authenticating via Ajax the cookies are automatically to subsequent requests.

Likewise with the [C#/.NET Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) the cookies will be retained on the Authenticated Service Client when specifying `RememberMe=true` when authenticating the request, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);

var authResponse = client.Post(new Authenticate {
    provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name,
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "p@55word",
    RememberMe = true,
});
```

You can then re-use the same instance for making authenticated requests:

```
var response = client.Post(new Secure { ... });
```

You can also transfer the cookies to a new client by assinging the `CookieContainer` e.g:

```
newClient.CookieContainer = client.CookieContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found not only the sessionId cookie needs to be passed to the consequent requests but also the whole container -ss-id, ss-pid, ss-opt, X-UAId-. I couldn't neither access the cookie container from the ICacheClient, I had to manually set the cookies when the authentication has place and the request all cookies for that container and add them to the new service call.